# Why do I need `position: absolute` in making side-by-side 2x2 square?

Tags: css, html

I use this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554055/164148) in the below example.

```
<!-- vim: set nowrap:-->
<html>
<style type="text/css">
        #titleImg{                 <!--No use in the code but it makes -->
                                   <!--things to work for some odd reason?!-->
                position:absolute; <!--If I remove this, FAILURE --not 2x2.-->
                                   <!--It becomes one-after-another after rem.-->
                                   <!--Why?-->
        }
        li{
                width:190px;
                height:190px;
                display: block;
                float: left;
                margin: 5px;
        }
</style>
<body>
        <center>

                <ul style="width:400px; height:400px; text-align:center;">
                        <li>
                                <img    id="titleImg"
                                src="../Pictures/Logos/logo.png" 
                                style="width:100%;height:100%"> 
                        </li>
                        <li> </li>
                        <li> </li>
                </ul>
        </center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't I think. Here's an updated jsFiddle example of what I believe you are trying to accomplish. Note: never use `<center></center>` tags - they are not good practice. Instead set the parent to `display: block` and its margin to `0 auto`.

Here is the new live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KvQCt/)

And the code:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li> <img src="http://www.woodlands-junior.kent.sch.uk/customs/images/uk.jpg"></li>
    <li> <img src="http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/images/u/us.gif"> </li>
    <li> <img src="http://www.enchantedlearning.com/school/Canada/flagbig.GIF"> </li>
</ul>
```

​
CSS

```
ul {
    display: block; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
    width:190px;
    height:190px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}​
```